# WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple table with two columns "referralID" & "studentID"

I can add like this

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO referralStudents (referralID,studentID) VALUES (?, ?)');
$stmt->execute([$myID,$studentID]);
```

I'm trying to get the WHERE NOT EXISTS statement to work. If there is already a row with both "referralID" & "studentID" don't add.

Both of these don't work can you show me where I'm going wrong?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO referralStudents (referralID,studentID) VALUES (?, ?) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM referralStudents WHERE referralID = ? and studentID = ?")');
$stmt->execute([$myID,$studentID,$myID,$studentID]);
        
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO referralStudents (referralID,studentID) VALUES (?, ?) WHERE NOT EXISTS (referralID,studentID) VALUES (?, ?)');
$stmt->execute([$myID,$studentID,$myID,$studentID]);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `SELECT` statement and not `VALUES` to apply the conditions of the `WHERE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO referralStudents (referralID,studentID) 
SELECT ?, ? 
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM referralStudents WHERE referralID = ? and studentID = ?)
```

You may remove `FROM dual` if your version of MySql is 8.0+.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7aad0a518d3b5a70ff9cdc5d2bfdb613).

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are empty i bet they are `NULL`. A field filled with `NULL` is existing but its content is `NULL` (`NULL` doesnt mean empty or non existing). Maybe this is what you need:

```
INSERT INTO refferalStudents (refferalID, studentID) VALUES (?,?) WHERE refferalID IS NULL AND studentID IS NULL
```